# How to reuse matched value of regex in JS replace() function in the function itself?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Let's say I have a string, I want to get a match in some string. To find it, I use regex, and then replace it. However, how would I replace it with the match itself but edited?

I'm having a hard time using match() and matchAll() because the input text is not necessarily a string and the outputs of the match functions aren't making sense at all in the context I'm using it in. They return as RegExpStringIterator(s).

Purpose:

Trying to make a google extension that edits content on the page.

Ex.

```
regex = /123/g
let text = "XYZ string is some string is a string, but 123 is what I want to change."
let edit = text.replace(regex, numGen(***not sure what to pass here***))

console.log(edit)

function numGen(match) {
//Here I want to get the match and add the string "4" to it
}

"""
Expected outcome of "console.log(edit)": 
XYZ string is some string is a string, but ***1234*** is what I want to change.
"""
```

Comment: How do you want to edit the match? Could you be more specific with what you want?

Comment: This is covered pretty clearly in the docs: [String.prototype.replace(): Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: @DemiPixel I edited the code snippet. I want to edit the match using something like this, match = match + "4". I want match to be edited in the replace() function.

Comment: @pilchard I checked many difference docs and sources but got more and more confused. I'll try again as I wait for responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this? Check inline comments

**UPD** with calling external function on match

```js
// External function to call with each match
const numGen = match => {
  // Here you get the match as argument from replace function
  // Then add the string "4" to it
  match += "4";
  // Then return final result back to replace
  return match;
}

// Replace method part
const regex = /string/g;
let counter = 0;
let text = "XYZ string is some string is a string.";

// Just set your external function as replace parameter.
// Matched string will be passed to it as arguments
let edit = text.replace(regex, numGen);

// Result
console.log(edit);
```

Comment: Your approach was different but helpful, however, I would like to understand how to edit the match or matches that was found by the regex in the replace function. I edited my post as well, please check the code. Thanks!

Comment: @SubZero ok, I see your update to question. Please, check my update to the answer. If it helps you, please accept it) thnx

Answer (score 3):

Based on your example, if you only need to append string/s (e.g. text) to the matched result, you can simply use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const regex = /123/g;
const text = "XYZ string is some string is a string, but 123 is what I want to change.";
const edit = text.replace(regex, '***$&***');
// $& means the whole matched string
// result: XYZ string is some string is a string, but ***123*** is what I want to change.
```

If you need to run some code to change the matched result, then you you can use a `replacerFunction`:

```js
const regex = /123/g;
const text = "XYZ string is some string is a string, but 123 is what I want to change.";
const edit = text.replace(regex, function(m) {
  // m here means the whole matched string
  // for example, let's double the number
  return m * 2;
  // resulat: XYZ string is some string is a string, but 246 is what I want to change.
});
```

Same as above but using arrow function:

```js
const regex = /123/g;
const text = "XYZ string is some string is a string, but 123 is what I want to change.";
const edit = text.replace(regex, m => {
  // m here means the whole matched string
  // for example, let's double the number
  return m * 2;
  // result: XYZ string is some string is a string, but 246 is what I want to change.
});
```

Note: For a single operation, above can also be written as:

```js
const edit = text.replace(regex, m => m * 2);
```

Comment: Ty for your help guys! Very clear and concise answers from the both of you. I wish I could accept 2 answers.

Comment: @tarkh Ty for your help guys! Very clear and concise answers from the both of you. I wish I could accept 2 answers.